# Remove empty lines in tab delimited file while preserving row labels

Tags: awk, sed, text-formatting

I have a tab delimited file with column headers like ID, A, B, C, D as shown in the pic below, and row labels too like a, b, c, d, e show below in pic. How do I remove all the empty lines (rows) while preserving the row labels with non-empty rows? Example input and desired output is shown below. Thank you for any help!

Sample input:

```
ID  A  B  C  D
a      1     2
b
c   1        1
d
e   1
```

Desired output:

```
ID  A  B  C  D
a      1     2
c   1        1
e   1
```

[sample input and output transcribed from original image]

Comment: When you have text output, [don't take a picture but copy paste the output in your POST](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Comment: Thank you Gilles. I am sorry and won't repeat it in the future. I had difficulty in formatting tables so I posted a pic instead. Can you point me to how to format a table here?

Comment: Just select all off your code, then in the editor click `{}`

Comment: See "Code Blocks" at https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 7):

What I suggest:

```
$ awk 'NF>1' file
I   A   B   C   D
a       1       2
c   1           1
e   1
```

Comment: The nitpicker in me would recommend adding `-F'\t'` for clarity (although the default FS of course also includes TAB in "contiguous runs of whitespace").

Comment: @AdminBee, well that might not work, actually. If the lines still have the tabs between each column (e.g. the third line would be `b\t\t\t\t`), `awk -F '\t'` would see the empty columns there and `NF` would be set accordingly. Then you'd need to loop over `$2` to `$NF` to see if any of them is non-empty.

Comment: @ilkkachu True, it depends on the definitive meaning of "empty" line. It remains a task for the OP to clarify that here.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed` or `grep`

```
$ sed -En '/[^ \t]*[ \t]/p' input_file
ID  A  B  C  D
a      1     2
c   1        1
e   1
```

```
$ grep -E '[^ \t]*[ \t]' input_file
ID  A  B  C  D
a      1     2
c   1        1
e   1
```